# Dart: AJAX form submit

Tags: ajax, post, dart, form-submit

**Please note: I am not interested in using Polymer for this; I want to use "pure" Dart!**

I am trying to build a simple sign-in screen for my Dart app, and am having difficulty getting the two form variables (`email` and `password`) to POST to the server-side:

Here's my main HTML file (`myapp.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sign in</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/myapp/myapp/myapp.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/myapp/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form id="signinForm" method="POST" class="form-signin">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="password" class="input-block-level" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="signinBtn" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="application/dart" src="myapp.dart"></script>
        <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my main Dart file (`myapp.dart`):

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
    querySelector("#signinForm")
        ..onClick.listen(handle);
}

void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    mouseEvent.preventDefault();

    FormElement formElement = mouseEvent.target as FormElement;

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/signinService";

    var request = HttpRequest.request(
        url,
        method: formElement.method,
        sendData: new FormData(formElement)
    ).then(onDataLoaded);
}

void onDataLoaded(HttpRequest req) {
    String response = req.responseText;
    if(response == 1)
        window.alert("You are signed in!");
    else
        window.alert("Sign in failed. Check credentials.");
}
```

When I run this in a browser I see the sign in screen appear, but when I click the signin button nothing happens, and Firebug throws a bunch of errors on the cross-compiled, obfuscated, minified JavaScript:

> : CastError: Casting value of type qE to incompatible type Yu

I want this to be an AJAX request so that the user does **not** have to experience a page reload (the intent here is to be a single page app).

Any ideas as to what's going on here? I'm almost 100% confident the issue isn't on the server-side, so for now I'm omitting to post server code. But I'll update my question with server code if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an example how to do this

[Forms, HTTP servers, and Polymer with Dart](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/09/forms-http-servers-and-polymer-with-dart.html)

When you change

```dart
void main() {
    querySelector("#signinBtn")
        ..onClick.listen(handle);
}
```

to

```dart
void main() {
    querySelector("form")
        .onSubmit.listen(handle);
}
```

you have access to target

```dart
void handle(Event event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    FormElement form = event.target as FormElement;

    ...
}
```

Comment: As always, thanks again @Gunter Zochbauer (+1) - I should have stated this at the outset (and have updated my question accordingly), but right now I'm not interested in using Polymer. I will eventually probably switch to Polymer and/or Angular, but for now want to learn "pure" Dart (no frameworks). Thanks again!

Comment: I think you should get what you want from this example anyway. Just how you bind to the events and how you access the values from the form fields is different.

Comment: What I miss in your example is where you assign email and password to the request. You actually send nothing to the server.

Comment: Thanks @Gunter Zochbauer (+1) - perhaps that's exactly what I'm missing! I guess I *assumed* that since the `<input>`s are inside a `<form>`, that Dart would put them in the body of the HTTP request (like a typical POST). Can you provide a code example of what to assign email/password to the request? Thanks again!

Comment: See the link in my answer. Step 4: `sendData: new FormData(form)`

Comment: Thanks again @Gunter Zochbauer (+1) so in that example the `form` variable is actually `target as FormElement`, which is passed in from a `submit(Event,var,Node)` method. Are you *sure* that this doesn't require any Polymer? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again @Gunter Zochbauer (+1 again) - I think we're getting closer. Please see my edits to both the HTML and the Dart file. Now when I click the sign in button, the client doesn't send any HTTP request to the server (I can tell by monitoring Firebug's Network panel), and instead it just produces a bunch of JS errors (again, see my edits). **Does anything in my code changes look wrong to you?** Thanks again!!!

Comment: Also, if I am adding a click-handler to the `signinForm`, doesn't that mean it will fire the AJAX request anytime a user clicks inside the form?!?

Comment: Nevermind it looks like I have 2 separate issues, and your answer helped me solve the first - thank you!!!

Comment: @CalifornianAcorn - My (and the referenced example) use onSubmit not onClick so your comment about clicking inside the form doesn't apply.

Would you please tell what solved your problem so this questions/answers will be useful to others too.

Sorry for the delay. I like supporting other Dart developers but I probably live in a different time zone (CET) and it's Christmas. 

Glad you solved it!
Merry Xmas!