# Sending node.js response and processing in client

Tags: node.js, dart

I have a server in node.js which handles registration from users.
When someone attempts to register I first check if the introduced email already exists in my database, and if not I send a response back saying that that email has already been used.

The problem is that when I send a response with `response.write()` when the browser receives the response it replaces all the webpage by the response text, and what I want is to use that response to display a message next to the form in the registration page.

I also want to get the response with a Dart event listener so that the client knows that the email is in use and can display the message. My code for making the HTTP request with Dart is the following:

```
signupSubmit.onClick.listen((e) {
    var req = new HttpRequest();

    req.onReadyStateChange.listen((e) {
      if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE) {
        print('Data submitted!');
      }
    });

    req.open('POST', signupForm.action);
    req.send(JSON.encode(serializeForm(signupForm)));
});


serializeForm(FormElement form) {
    var data = {};

    form.querySelectorAll('input,select').forEach((Element el) {
        if (el is InputElement)
           data[el.name] = el.value;
    });

    return data;
}
```

So how can I send a response that I can process in the client?
And how can I get the server response with Dart?

Comment: I guess you find solutions for your problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801516 or here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749740

Comment: Here are articles about this topic https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/#submitting-a-form and
http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/06/forms-http-servers-and-web-components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `signupSubmit` click seems to submit its `<form>`. You can block the default form submission with :

```dart
signupForm.onSubmit.listen((e) => e.preventDefault());
```

Comment: I don't think that´s the problem, as `signupSubmit` isn't a `<input type="submit">` but a `<button id="signupSubmit"></button>`

Comment: By default a `<button>` (without `type`) is a _submit_ button. See [The BUTTON element section of the html spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).