# AngularDart - Use Form Action

Tags: html, forms, templates, dart

I am trying to use a form action attribute in AngularDart to redirect to the specified url. In plain html I would do something like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8082" method="GET">
   <select name="q">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
      </select>
   <input type="Submit" value="Guess">
</form>
```

How would I implement this functionality with AngularDart?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular you would instead do the request in code, because `form action="..."` would reload the application or even another page which usually is not what you want in a single page application (SPA):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
```

and then post the form in Dart code like shown in the question in [Dart: AJAX form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749740/dart-ajax-form-submit)

I haven't done this myself in years and don't have a full example, but it should get you going.

Comment: Cool, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I have now sent a request from my client to my server. My server received it. Is there a special function for HttpRequest in the dart:io in order to get the data I sent with the dart:html HttpRequest from my client?

Comment: Some example code `import 'dart:convert'; ... if (request.method == 'POST') {
        final requestData = await request.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
        final json = JSON.decode(requestData) as Map<String, dynamic>;}`. Perhaps it's somewhat different if you use `FormData`. I never used that.